Function that is (essentially) a self-convolution but not a multiple of a self-convolution
Call a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to C$ nice if it is of the form $F = f\ast \tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f}(x) = \overline{f(-x)}$. (Of course nice functions are precisely those whose Fourier transform is non-negative.)
Is there such a thing as a continuous, compactly supported, nice function $F$ such that $F(t) (1+i t)$ is real-valued, but not itself nice?
Related question: Functions such that the *integral* of the Fourier transform is non-negative?
(It is not hard to show that, if $F(t) (1+i t)$ is nice, then so is $F(t)$ (at least if you assume $F$ is absolutely continuous, etc.).)
